# Get data only from the first result of a Json

Tags: javascript, json

[image: This is the JSON I am getting]

I want to get the data from the only the first result of the results
I am collecting the JSON in a var called response and try to get by this code

```
if (message.body.startsWith('!movie ')) {
    const movieName = message.body.slice(7)

    const APIKey ='API_KEY_HERE';
    const BaseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    const searchURL = BaseURL + '/search/movie?api_key=' + APIKey+ '&query=' + movieName;


    https.get(searchURL, function (response) {

      var name = response.results[0].title;
      console.log(data.name);
      
        try {
          obj = JSON.parse(name);
          message.reply(`${obj.setup} \n${obj.punchline}`);
        } catch (err) {
          return message.reply(err);
        }
    
    });

  }
```

But I am getting errors at this line

[image: Error]

**json :**

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=API_KEY_HERE&query=harry%20potter

```
error as text : 
var name = response.results[0].title;
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at RedirectableRequest.<anonymous> (E:\ww-wra-main\index.js:99:34)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at RedirectableRequest._processResponse (E:\ww-wra-main\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:399:10)
    at ClientRequest.RedirectableRequest._onNativeResponse (E:\ww-wra-main\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:57:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:647:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:515:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ww-wra-google@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ww-wra-google@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\91787\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-12T11_09_50_568Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You should add the error to your question.

Comment: Can you add the json data as text format instead of a pic.

Comment: that means `response.results` is undefined

Comment: Same for the error, please add to the question as text.

Comment: you need to show the code that requests that data

Comment: Done...All the required changes are made to the question

Comment: please read [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) on how to use https.get ... i.e. `res.on('data', (d) => {` etc

Comment: Can you please tell what's wrong in it?

Comment: also, not sure why you'd think the `title` property would be `JSON` string with a setup and punchline propert

Comment: @KRISHNA - yes, you're not reading the response - as ***documented*** - nowhere near the correct code, and your expectations of the response are completely wrong too

Comment: Oh yaa...That's a mistake

Comment: By the way - not smart publishing your API key - unscrupulous people may start using it for themselves

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting what exactly I should do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bravo suggested in the comment, the problem here is the way you are trying to fetch the response from the api using the `https` module from NodeJS.
As you can see from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback), the response is not received directly as a string in the `response` variable there. `https.get` will give you an object with which you can fetch the response, which is received as chunks.

This would be the correct way of fetching the result:

```js
const https = require("https")

const movieName = "Terminator"

const APIKey ='<<your_api_key>>';
const BaseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
const searchURL = BaseURL + '/search/movie?api_key=' + APIKey+ '&query=' + movieName;


https.get(searchURL, function (response) {
    var content = ""

    response.on("data", function(partial_content) {
        content += partial_content
    })

    response.on("end", function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(content)

        var name = data.results[0].title;

        console.log(name)
        // message.reply(name)
    })
})
```

You have to append the data received in `response.on("data")` until the `response.on("end")` is called, and there you can handle the response.

---

If using the `https` core module from node is difficult, you can try using a higher-level external npm module like `axios`

```js
const axios = require("axios")

const movieName = "Terminator"

const APIKey = '<<your_api_key>>';
const BaseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
const searchURL = BaseURL + '/search/movie?api_key=' + APIKey+ '&query=' + movieName;


axios.get(searchURL)
.then(function(response) {
    // axios also direcltly parses the JSON response in this case
    var content = response.data
    var name = content.results[0].title

    console.log(name)
    // message.reply(name)
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error occured:", error)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering...And yes its working
I just wanted to use this API for some temporary use and I didn't use much APIs and not even JS...So I didn't know these things Sorry for that